# DIV.click() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use Chrome's console to programatically click on the video area in order to play it.

This is the page https://www.onitube.com/video/11403/seinfeld-s01e03-the-robbery

The `<video` tag is inside an iframe, so I am trying to click the `<div` tag which is the parent of the `<iframe` but I get `undefined` error in the console.

That is the code which is generating the error
`document.getElementById("flash").click()`

Any idea why this is happening and how to click that div? Will it play the video? or the video tag being inside an iframe is a problem?

**UPDATE #1**

Thanks to @PatrickEvans it turns out that undefined is not an error, just the return value of the click() method (see his comments)

Comment: `document.getElementById` doesn't search iframe contents for elements. You need to get the `document` of the iframe in order to do that. And if it is an external domain you more than likely will not have access to do that via js from your own page

Comment: @PatrickEvans the iframe does not contain the div it is the other way around

Comment: @PatrickEvans am trying to click the div which has the iframe (am aware of cross origin policy, but I will be using -disable-web-security

Comment: Then there is no element with an id of `flash` in your page. If it is loaded dynamically, you might be calling getElementById before it is loaded

Comment: @PatrickEvans this is a screenshot https://ibb.co/f7i3JJ and I am running the console after all DOM are loaded, like 10 min after page is loaded

Comment: i can get it to works by
`var v = document.getElementById("video_1_html5_api"); 
v.play();`

please try

Comment: @RizkiDPrast It plays but I want to click not play

Comment: I don't get an error when trying to call `click()` method what error exactly do you get?

Comment: @PatrickEvans this is the error https://ibb.co/cNvdky

Comment: That is not an error, that is just the return value of the function, which in this case event methods don't have return values so the console shows `undefined`

Comment: what are you expecting by clicking `DIV` tag??

Comment: @PatrickEvans I see...am new to JS so didnt know, basically I am trying to invoke a click on any element that leads to video playing. not using .play() cross origin policy is not a problem

Answer (score -2):

```
document.getElementById("myiframe").contentWindow.document.getElementById("myid0").onclick = function(){
    console.log("yayay")
}
```

I hope you understand the concept

Comment: Doesnt this mean that whenever my element is clicked, then the console will show this message? I am trying to click using javascript not attach a handler that does something when the click has already happened

Comment: .onclick = null;